# Instead of using a hex code for a color, make it transparent [AS3]

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So lets say I have some code in as3, and it requires a given color (Current one is 0x701100 for example) but instead of giving it a hex color code, I want it to be transparent, aka no color, aka see through, you get what I mean.
This is basically the line of code that determines what color it is: `super(0x701100, 0x8D1500);` and well the 0x8D1500 represents some other things color, but all I want is the 0x701100 to be transparent/not show.

Comment: You have to add opacity treatment in that code using [`ColorTransform`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html) ... you can not pass opacity inside a color value.

Comment: What is the object you apply color to?

Comment: `0x00701100` is supported by some things in AS3 (BitmapData for instance), where the first two zeroes after the x are the transparency value.  You haven't given any context to what kind of object this should be applied to so it's impossibly to tell you exactly what to do.

Comment: I solved this by doing `this.backgroundBox.alpha = 0;` and well the `0x701100` is obviously what the color of the `backgroundBox` was.

Comment: Your question is not related to your actual problem. Next time post a complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color `0x701100` is already "transparent" in that it has no value for an alpha channel. It's the same as `0x00701100`. A value such as `0xff701100` would represent a fully opaque color, and `0x80701100` would be about 50% transparent. Obviously, the problem is that your `super()` method does not support rendering transparency from the hex color.